# Libgdx collision detection between sprites using border of sprite, not a rectangle or circle

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using libgdx in android studio, and I am working with sprite collision detection. I need to know how to detect a collision between two irregularly shaped sprites. My sprites are created from png image textures. Is it possible to use the border of the sprite as the detection surface? Using a rectangle or circle drawn around the sprite will not be accurate enough. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Box2D](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d) which is a great and easy to learn library for physics and lighting. After setting bodies correctly, you can set body shape as rectangle, circle, square or any custom shape using paths, you don't need to worry about collision at all. You only take care what should happen while or after collision

Comment: I am working with Box2D, but I do not know how to set a body as a custom shape using paths, I can only figure out how to set the body to a rectangle or circle. The collision part isn't a problem, I just can't figure out how to make a custom shape for the body

Comment: You need to create `Vector2[]` vertices and create a `PolygonShape` and add vertices to PolygonShape. `PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
  shape.set(vertices);`

Comment: I haven't been building games for a year. I can't remember all the details for creating Vertices but they are (x,y) positions for your shape and there supposed to be some programs for creating custom shapes if you can't figure out exact sprite shape. You could create custom body by touching your sprite on one of these programs, they probably got better since last year. Google it, and you will find it. It's not hard but i honestly don't remember the specifics.